# How can I retrieve the instance of a class from a value of one of its attributes?

Tags: python

I'd like to (elegantly) serialise a connection between attributes in different class instances.  For example:

```
class AttrClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

class ObjClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self.foo = AttrClass(value=value)

out_obj = ObjClass('out', value='bar')
in_obj = ObjClass('in', value=out_obj.foo)
in_obj.foo
# Result: <AttrClass object at 0x000001B086B0A470>
```

In this case though I'd also like to find the `out_obj` instance of the ObjClass class and the attribute name `foo`.  It could be done if `self` and `'foo'` was passed into the AttrClass initialisation but that would be annoying for the user to keep entering it every time they created a new attribute with that class as the value.

Is there a way that I can trace up from a value to the attribute name it's the value of and the class instance that attribute belongs to?

Alternatively, is there a way you can automatically add the class instance and attribute name to a class upon instantiation?  For example:

```
class AttrClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.host_class = self.do_magic_class_thing()
        self.host_attr = self.do_magic_attr_thing()

out_obj = ObjClass('out', value='bar')
in_obj = ObjClass('in', value=out_obj.foo)
in_obj.foo.host_class.name
# Result: 'out'
```

Comment: I believe there is no way to do so as the value is evaluated at the point of reference i.e. `out_obj.foo` will not leave any information about host_object unless (1) send to host_object in or (2) use the inspect trick which is hacky and not elegant.

Comment: Even though you say it's hacky... could you indulge me and tell me how one would go about using this "inspect trick"? ;)

Comment: put the answer below. see if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, at least not elegantly - you could do it with a lot of `inspect` magic but it would turn pretty ugly pretty fast. This 'problem' exists in pretty much all languages that depend on their interpreters/VMs to do memory management via reference counting - if children of objects were to store references to their parents you would get a circular reference count that's not fast to resolve and is riddled with gotchas so language designers usually elect to not do it and leave it to developers to handle their own particular cases.

So, in your particular case, since you're wrapping your values `AttrClass` instances, you can have those instances keep a reference to their parents as:

```
class AttrClass(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, value=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = value

class ObjClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self.foo = AttrClass(self, value=value)

out_obj = ObjClass('out', value='bar')
in_obj = ObjClass('in', value=out_obj.foo)

assert in_obj.foo.value.parent is out_obj  # passes
print(in_obj.foo.value.parent.name)  # out
```

Also, is there any particular reason why you need to write your own serializers/deserializers? There are a ton of such out there and I'm sure at least some fit your use cases. I wholeheartedly recommend [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html).

Comment: Good to know I'm not asking a dumb question with an obvious answer then. :)  The "elegant" part was more to do with how this connection is represented in the json file I wanted to export.  I wanted to use JSON just because it's standard, ascii based (and therefore more secure than pickle) and doesn't require any external modules.

Answer (score 0):

There you go. This code has zero guarantees because it relies on Python stack frame support in the interpreter implementation.

```
import inspect, re


class AttrClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

        stack = inspect.stack()     # get the stack
        goback = stack[2]           # go down the stack 2 step
        entry_point = goback[4]     # get the code context to get "object name" [4] is from stack format

        name = re.findall("ObjClass\(.*value=([^)]*)\)", entry_point[0])  # magic hack to get "out_obj"
        if len(name) > 0:
            obj_name = name[0].split('.')[0]    # get the object's name.

            argvalues = inspect.getargvalues(goback.frame)[3]       # [3] to get `locals` from tuple returned.

            if obj_name in argvalues:
                setattr(self, 'host_class', argvalues[obj_name])    # iject the attribute

        else:   #Sorry can't find it
            setattr(self, 'host_class', None)


class ObjClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self.foo = AttrClass(value=value)


out_obj = ObjClass('out', value='bar')
in_obj = ObjClass('in', value=out_obj.foo)

print(in_obj.foo.host_class.name)
```

Comment: Cool thanks!  It doesn't look like the most robust thing ever (e.g. querying stuff by how the code is presented) but it's really cool in giving me an idea about how inspect and frames work.  Haven't worked with that stuff before.  Thanks.